# Member function overriding accross class hierarchy

Tags: c++

I have defined a class A and derived a new class B from A .
I have overloaded SetData() function in class B.
When I tried to access SetData function of class B using object of B, compiler doesn't permit it. Why is it so ?

```
class A{

 public :
       void SetData();    
};

class B : public A {

 public:
       void SetData(int);   
};

B b;
b.SetData() ; // error
```

Comment: Well, one could always start by reading the error.

Comment: code looks valid. Please post the exact error message your getting.

Comment: BTW, which operator is overloaded here?

Comment: Note that what you do in the sample code is called "overriding". Should you wish to research the subject, google "overload override".

Comment: hi I have overloaded funtion here not operator..and the code is for funtion overloading since 2nd one has int as parameter..

Comment: Neither overloading, nor overriding is done here. What's done is called hiding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OMG, no error message.  -1 for you.

But let us use telepathy and guess your error message.  You're getting something like "symbol not found" because you try to call a function `B::SetData()` which doesn't have a body.  And it must have a body even if it does nothing and even if it's declared in parent class!  Try adding it into the body of your class

```
class B : public A {
 public:
       void SetData(int)
       {  /* add body here */ };   
};
```

**or** outside of it

```
class B : public A {

 public:
       void SetData(int);   
};
void B::SetData(int)
{
  //write it here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
b.SetData(2) ; // error
```

I don't see any problem in calling `SetData(2)`.

Where as if you call `b.SetData() ;` then there will be an error. When you define a method with same name in in derived class the base class methods with same name will be hidden in derived class.

You can make them visible in derived class by `using` keyword.

```
class A{

 public :
     void SetData(){}   
};

class B : public A {

 public:

     using A::SetData;
     void SetData(int){}   
};



int main() 
{ 
B b;
b.SetData() ; // error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What i guess you might be facing

**error: unresolved external symbol**

write code as suggested by Pavel Shved